# What is the best way to wrap onsen ui list item to 'a' tag?

Tags: onsen-ui

I try to make clickable list item using `ons-list-item`. When I display my entries like

```
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
    ...
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
    ...
    </ons-list-item>
```

they are displayed properly.

But list separators disappear when I try to wrap `ons-list-item` to `a` tag.
What is the best way to make `ons-list-item` handle links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways here. Using HTML:

```
<a href="http://......">
   <ons-list-item>
      Item title
   </ons-list-item>
</a>
```

This one is what you already tried. It will change the style of the text, the pointer and other stuff unless you specify something different.

Using JavaScript:

```
<ons-list-item onclick="window.location='http://......';">
   Item title
</ons-list-item>
```

This one does not change the CSS, so if you don't have any problem with JavaScript it may be a solution. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. It may be overkill, but i already bind ng-click to angular controller where change document.location. Your solution is much simpler.